# Using PhoneGap and SQLite insert statement

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

We're having some trouble using an SQLite database in a PhoneGap application. This is how we create the database:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipe (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT, thumbnail TEXT, 
    instructions TEXT)'
);
```

And this is how we put the data in:

```
var myquery = 'INSERT INTO recipe (name, instructions) VALUES (?, ?)';
tx.executeSql(myquery, [name, instructietext], function(tx, results){
    recipeid = results.insertId;
}, errorCB);
```

In the callback we print the error message in an allert:

```
Error number: 5
Error message: Could not prepare statement (1 2 values for 3 columns)
```

Comment: first, you shouldn't use "name" as a column-key as it might be reserved. did you try setting all 3 values? name, instructions & thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @datayeah We've tried to rename name to something else. But unfortunately that's not the issue. Also we tried to add all three fields, the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine, it was an other transaction that failed. Somehow it did that other transaction before this one. The order it was in code didn't matter.